# Replace multiple html tags in vb.net

Tags: html, asp.net, vb.net

This code is for replace with bold tag `<b>`, I am passing from front end "{b}test {/b}". This only works when tags are in different rows. if the same row has more than one tag , it is consider first and last tags only, please help

```
Public Shared Function ReplaceAllLinks(ByVal AdditionalInfo As String) As String

    Dim builder As New StringBuilder(AdditionalInfo)
    For Each match As Match In Regex.Matches(AdditionalInfo, "{b}(?<BOLD>.*){/b}", RegexOptions.IgnoreCase)          
        builder.Replace(match.Value, $"<b>{match.Groups("BOLD").Value}</b>")
    Next
    Return builder.ToString()
End Function
```

Comment: Try adding [RegexOptions.SingleLine](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.text.regularexpressions.regexoptions?view=netcore-3.1#System_Text_RegularExpressions_RegexOptions_Singleline) as well as IgnoreCase

Comment: But also check on lines like `"text {b}bold1{/b} more text {b}bold2{/b}" - you may need a non-greedy match